# Can't access variable inside angular.js controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

This is my controller:

```
app.controller("PlaceController", ['$http', function($http){

    this.places = shops;
    var hotels = this;
    hotels.objects = [];
    this.spots = new Array;

    this.newPlace = {};

    this.city = new String();

    this.addPlace = function() {
        this.places.push(this.newPlace);
        this.newPlace = {};

        var request = *some query syntax, sorry for hiding*

        $http.get(request).success(function(data) {
            hotels.objects = data;
            console.log(hotels.objects.elements);
        });

        for (each in hotels.objects.elements) {
          this.spots.push(each.tags.name);
        };

        console.log(this.spots);

}}] );
```

I get an empty array when I log `this.spots` to the console. The http request etc work perfectly because the `console.log(hotels.objects.elements)` statement works perfectly.

Because of this problem, I can't output it into my HTML either. What should I do?

Comment: `$http.get` is async, so when you do `for` loop `hotels.objects` is empty array

Comment: ``this.spots = new Array;`` should be ``this.spots = new Array();``

Comment: @DreadBoy nope, this not matter - just try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding to the `spots` array before the ajax request is done, move your calls to push inside the callback:

```
$http.get(request).success(function(data) {
        hotels.objects = data;
        console.log(hotels.objects.elements);
        angular.forEach(hotels.objects.elements, function(value) {
                hotels.spots.push(value.tags.name);
        });
});
```

Also, you should really be using `$scope` instead of references to `this`. This would simplify your code a bit, without needing to rename `this` to `hotels`

**full controller code using `$scope`**

```
app.controller("PlaceController", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.places = shops;    
    $scope.objects = [];
    $scope.spots = new Array;
    $scope.newPlace = {};
    $scope.city = new String();

    $scope.addPlace = function() {
        $scope.places.push($scope.newPlace);
        $scope.newPlace = {};

        var request = *some query syntax, sorry for hiding*

        $http.get(request).success(function(data) {
            $scope.objects = data;
            console.log($scope.objects.elements);

            angular.forEach($scope.objects.elements, function(value, key) {
                $scope.spots.push(value.tags.name);
            });
            // spots is ready, log it, do whatever
            console.log($scope.spots);
        });       
}}] );
```

**NOTE:** Using `$scope` means you won't need to call `this` from your html to reference the objects and functions defined in your controller.

An example:

```
<div ng-controller="PlaceController">
    <!-- no need to call places.city, if you use $scope just write city -->
    {{city}}
</div>
```

**EDIT**: You probably shouldn't use JavaScript's `for-in`, the problem with it is that it iterates on the **names or indexes** of your objects/arrays.

An example:

```
var someArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for (i in someArray) {
   console.log(i); // prints 0, 1, 2
   console.log(someArray[i]); // prints 'a', 'b', 'c'
}
```

This is different from any for-in/for-each implementation in other popular languages.

Anyway, in this case I've edited the code above to use Angular's `forEach`, which is a more appropriate solution (many libraries implement custom for-each functions to fix JS's weird `for-in`)
You can read more in [Angular's docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

Another option, in **plain javascript** is, if `$scope.objects.elements` is an array, using the [`map()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), like this:

```
$scope.spots = $scope.objects.elements.map(function(value) {
    return value.tags.name; // value is an item in object.elements
});
```

Comment: in angular2 not use `scope` and for migration suggest use `controller as` syntax

Comment: Angular2 isn't released yet and given that it's going to be incompatible anyway, regardless if you use $scope or not, I don't see the issue.

Comment: angular2 is in developer preview at the moment it does not make sense to base production code off of it or even prefer to work in it right now

Comment: Hey Sosdoc, I tried it! But it's causing another problem. I get an error saying that the 'name' property can't be accessed in the "$scope.spots.push(each.tags.name)" line. I didn't receive that error in my original code, what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: @AMANAGARWAL I've edited the answer fixing something that was *probably* wrong. If that doesn't work, you should show the output of `console.log($scope.objects.elements);`

Comment: @Sosdoc wow, it worked!!!! You're amazing! You're awesome! Damn, can you tell me what exactly you did there? Could you please tell me what I need to learn and where I can learn it to be able to do that myself next time? Thanks again!

Comment: @AMANAGARWAL I've written some explanations after my **EDIT**, javascript is an easy language to learn but has a lot of hidden pitfalls. If you want to learn more I heartily recommend Mozilla's [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and if you're into javascript you should be required to read Douglas Crockford's "Javascript: the good parts".

Answer (score 3):

You are issuing an asynchronous request to get the spots, but you're logging them before they complete.

Change `this.addPlace` to log / act on the spots array inside the promise callback:

```
this.addPlace = function() {
    this.places.push(this.newPlace);
    this.newPlace = {};

    var request = *some query syntax, sorry for hiding*

    $http.get(request).success(function(data) {
        hotels.objects = data;
        console.log(hotels.objects.elements);

        for (each in hotels.objects.elements) {
          this.spots.push(each.tags.name);
        };

        console.log(this.spots);
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure that "this.spots" will still work inside of the http request function? The console gives me an error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined", is there a way around that?

Comment: `this` doesn't refer to the same item inside the callback, it should be `hotels` in this case.

Comment: @Sosdoc even replacing "this" with "hotels" doesn't work here. Earlier it couldn't read the property 'push', now it can't read 'name'. Why does that give the same error but for different properties if I change 'this.spots' to 'hotels.spots'?

Comment: @AMANAGARWAL it's the same problem I was discussing in my answer, the way you used the for-in was wrong as it was iterating on property names, `each` doesn't refer to items but just names.

Answer (score 0):

try this ..

due to your async call you need to perform task inside success

```
$http.get(request).success(function(data) {
        hotels.objects = data;
        console.log(hotels.objects.elements);

         for (each in hotels.objects.elements) {
              hotels.spots.push(each.tags.name);
          };

        console.log(this.spots);
    });
```

Comment: due to your async call you need to perform task inside success

Comment: so add explanation in your answer :-)

Comment: happy now ? i was in hurry that time :D

Comment: without any explanation your code just duplicate part of other answer, so better remove it than add, and if i not mistaken, first version of your answer was wrong.